# MathArt contest about Aesthetic Conformal Image Mapping

Tags: complex-numbers, math-contests

At the moment a MathArt contest is running about Aesthetic Conformal Image Mapping were individuals and classes can participate:
https://www.freelancer.com/contest/MathArt-Contest-Aesthetic-Conformal-Image-Mapping-ACIM_a-2269317/details

Goal is to find non trivial closed form expressions of complex, especially conformal functions that deform images in an aesthetic interesting way.

Code for Matlab and links for Mathematica and Maple are given and those who have no experience with such Math programs can experiment with G'MIC and G'MIC Online.

It is a kind of recursive contest were interesting closed form expressions will be selected, parametrized and included in an open library for aesthetic mathematical image mappings as a stepping stone for upcoming versions of this contests held once or twice a year.

Comment: Welcome to MESE! This is not a question. You should edit it into a question about math art contests and post your contest information as an answer.

Comment: You shoul'd've posted on meta